# Android round rectangle with 1 coloured corner

Tags: java, android, shapes

I have a round rectangle shape like this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <gradient
        android:endColor="#6d6d6d"
        android:centerColor="#6d6d6d"
        android:startColor="#6d6d6d"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Is it possible to make the right-down corner in another colour than the rest?

Comment: post an image describing what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You can use 9-patch image for this.